# Different results VS C++ and GNU g++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I have a program that works in VS C++ and does not work with g++. Here is the code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

#define EP 1e-10

using namespace std;

typedef pair<long long, long long> ii;
typedef pair<bool, int> bi;
typedef vector<ii> vii;

// Returns the orientation of three points in 2D space
int orient2D(ii pt0, ii pt1, ii pt2)
{
    long long result = (pt1.first - pt0.first)*(pt2.second - pt0.second) 
        - (pt1.second - pt0.second)*(pt2.first - pt0.first);
    return result == 0 ? 0 : result < 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

// Returns the angle derived from law of cosines center-pt1-pt2.
// Defined to be negative if pt2 is to the right of segment pt1 to center
double angle(ii center, ii pt1, ii pt2)
{
    double aS = pow(center.first - pt1.first, 2) + pow(center.second - pt1.second, 2);
    double bS = pow(pt2.first - pt1.first, 2) + pow(pt2.second - pt1.second, 2);
    double cS = pow(center.first - pt2.first, 2) + pow(center.second - pt2.second, 2);

/*  long long aS = (center.first - pt1.first)*(center.first - pt1.first) + (center.second - pt1.second)*(center.second - pt1.second);
    long long bS = (pt2.first - pt1.first)*(pt2.first - pt1.first) + (pt2.second - pt1.second)*(pt2.second - pt1.second);
    long long cS = (center.first - pt2.first)*(center.first - pt2.first) + (center.second - pt2.second)*(center.second - pt2.second);*/

    int sign = orient2D(pt1, center, pt2);

    return sign == 0 ? 0 : sign * acos((aS + bS - cS) / ((sqrt(aS) * sqrt(bS) * 2)));
}

// Computes the average point of the set of points
ii centroid(vii &pts)
{
    ii center(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        center.first += pts[i].first;
        center.second += pts[i].second;
    }

    center.first /= pts.size();
    center.second /= pts.size();

    return center;
}

// Uses monotone chain to convert a set of points into a convex hull, ordered counter-clockwise
vii convexHull(vii &pts)
{
    sort(pts.begin(), pts.end());
    vii up, dn;
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        while (up.size() > 1 && orient2D(up[up.size()-2], up[up.size()-1], pts[i]) >= 0)
            up.pop_back();
        while (dn.size() > 1 && orient2D(dn[dn.size()-2], dn[dn.size()-1], pts[i]) <= 0)
            dn.pop_back();

        up.push_back(pts[i]);
        dn.push_back(pts[i]);
    }

    for (int i = up.size()-2; i > 0; --i)
    {
        dn.push_back(up[i]);
    }

    return dn;
}

// Tests if a point is critical on the polygon, i.e. if angle center-qpt-polygon[i]
// is larger (smaller) than center-qpt-polygon[i-1] and center-qpt-polygon[i+1].
// This is true iff qpt-polygon[i]-polygon[i+1] and qpt-polygon[i]-polygon[i-1]
// are both left turns (min) or right turns (max)
bool isCritical(vii &polygon, bool mx, int i, ii qpt, ii center)
{
    int ip1 = (i + 1) % polygon.size();
    int im1 = (i + polygon.size() - 1) % polygon.size();

    int p1sign = orient2D(qpt, polygon[i], polygon[ip1]);
    int m1sign = orient2D(qpt, polygon[i], polygon[im1]);

    if (p1sign == 0 && m1sign == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (mx)
    {
        return p1sign <= 0 && m1sign <= 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return p1sign >= 0 && m1sign >= 0;
    }
}

// Conducts modified binary search on the polygon to find tangent lines in O(log n) time.
// This is equivalent to finding a max or min in a "parabola" that is rotated and discrete.
// Vanilla binary search does not work and neither does vanilla ternary search. However, using
// the fact that there is only a single max and min, we can use the slopes of the points at start
// and mid, as well as their values when compared to each other, to determine if the max or min is
// in the left or right section
bi find_tangent(vii &polygon, bool mx, ii qpt, int start, int end, ii center)
{
    // When query is small enough, iterate the points. This avoids more complicated code dealing with the cases not possible as
    // long as left and right are at least one point apart. This does not affect the asymptotic runtime.
    if (end - start <= 4)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
        {
            if (isCritical(polygon, mx, i, qpt, center))
            {
                return bi(true, i);
            }
        }

        return bi(false, -1);
    }

    int mid = (start + end) / 2;

    // use modulo to wrap around the polygon
    int startm1 = (start + polygon.size() - 1) % polygon.size();
    int midm1 = (mid + polygon.size() - 1) % polygon.size();

    // left and right angles
    double startA = angle(center, qpt, polygon[start]);
    double midA = angle(center, qpt, polygon[mid]);

    // minus 1 angles, to determine slope
    double startm1A = angle(center, qpt, polygon[startm1]);
    double midm1A = angle(center, qpt, polygon[midm1]);

    int startSign = abs(startm1A - startA) < EP ? 0 : (startm1A < startA ? 1 : -1);
    int midSign = abs(midm1A - midA) < EP ? 0 : (midm1A < midA ? 1 : -1);

    bool left = true;
    // naively 27 cases: left and left angles can be <, ==, or >,
    // slopes can be -, 0, or +, and each left and left has slopes,
    // 3 * 3 * 3 = 27. Some cases are impossible, so here are the remaining 18.
    if (abs(startA - midA) < EP)
    {
        if (startSign == -1)
        {
            left = !mx;
        }
        else
        {
            left = mx;
        }
    }
    else if (startA < midA)
    {
        if (startSign == 1)
        {
            if (midSign == 1)
            {
                left = false;
            }
            else if (midSign == -1)
            {
                left = mx;
            }
            else
            {
                left = false;
            }
        }
        else if (startSign == -1)
        {
            if (midSign == -1)
            {
                left = true;
            }
            else if (midSign == 1)
            {
                left = !mx;
            }
            else
            {
                left = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (midSign == -1)
            {
                left = false;
            }
            else
            {
                left = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (startSign == 1)
        {
            if (midSign == 1)
            {
                left = true;
            }
            else if (midSign == -1)
            {
                left = mx;
            }
            else
            {
                left = true;
            }
        }
        else if (startSign == -1)
        {
            if (midSign == -1)
            {
                left = false;
            }
            else if (midSign == 1)
            {
                left = !mx;
            }
            else
            {
                left = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (midSign == 1)
            {
                left = true;
            }
            else
            {
                left = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (left)
    {
        return find_tangent(polygon, mx, qpt, start, mid+1, center);
    }
    else
    {
        return find_tangent(polygon, mx, qpt, mid, end, center);
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vii rawPoints(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> rawPoints[i].first >> rawPoints[i].second;
    }

    vii polygon = convexHull(rawPoints);
    set<ii> points(polygon.begin(), polygon.end());
    ii center = centroid(polygon);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        ii pt;
        cin >> pt.first >> pt.second;

        bi top = find_tangent(polygon, true, pt, 0, polygon.size(), center);
        bi bot = find_tangent(polygon, false, pt, 0, polygon.size(), center);

        // a query point is inside if it is collinear with its max (top) and min (bot) angled points, it is a polygon point, or if none of the points are critical
        if (!top.first || orient2D(polygon[top.second], pt, polygon[bot.second]) == 0 || points.count(pt))
        {
            cout << "INSIDE" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << polygon[top.second].first << " " << polygon[top.second].second << " " << polygon[bot.second].first << " " << polygon[bot.second].second << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is there's something wrong with the `angle` function. I have narrowed it down to either that or `find_tangent`. I also see different results in g++ when I switch from `double` to `long long` in the `angle` function. The `double` results are closer to correct, but I can't see why it should be any different. The values I'm feeding in are small and no overflow/ rounding should be causing issues. I have also seen differences in doing `pow(x, 2)` or `x*x` when I assign to a double. I don't understand why this would make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the input file: https://github.com/brycesandlund/Coursework/blob/master/Java/PrintPoints/points.txt

Here is the correct result:
https://github.com/brycesandlund/Coursework/blob/master/CompGeo/CompGeo/correct.txt

Here is the incorrect result:
https://github.com/brycesandlund/Coursework/blob/master/CompGeo/CompGeo/fast.txt

Comment: What is the expected result and what is the actual one?

Comment: Added the input, correct, and incorrect files @ChristianHackl.

Comment: Narrowing it down to a method that calls the other functions and concludes with a recursive call isn't really narrowing it down. Is it possible to reduce this to a simple example that shows the behavior.

Comment: `g++ -Wall -Wextra` says that you're not using `center` in `isCritical` - is that intentional?

Comment: Let me clarify, I have a program that runs a simpler algorithm and uses all functions other than `angle` and `find_tangent`: https://github.com/brycesandlund/Coursework/blob/master/CompGeo/CompGeo/HW2Dumb.cpp. I'll work on a simpler example.

Yes, not using `center` in `isCritical` is intentional. I'll remove the parameter.

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine, after compiling with g++, and it gives a different set of results than your "correct" (quite a few lines that are different). Which tells me that the problem is not with the compiler, but with something in your code.

Comment: Mats, visual studio will produce the correct results. g++ will not. It will also not look exactly like my incorrect results, since the end of the line in the output file may be the result of referencing unallocated memory.

Comment: Ok, in that case clang++ is ALSO equally wrong. Which I find unlikely, as they are entirely different in their internal design as compilers. Possibly the same standard library, but again, I doubt that is wrong for "ordinary" inputs of commonly used functions.

Comment: Add logging of inputs and outputs to each function. Run it in both compilers. Text diff the output logs.

Comment: I can tell that calculating the value as `long long` or `double` makes no difference in `angle` - I added a version of both, and compared the end result, and it comes up with exactly the same result for both.

Comment: Interesting observation: If I compile the code with clang -m32, I get the "correct.txt" output.

Comment: There is however no difference between `angle` using `*` and `long long` and using `double` and `pow2`. I just tried...

Comment: However, I expect you don't really want "not a number" as the result, so that may be a reason why you get strange results!

Comment: See my answer. I took @ZanLynx's suggestion and debugged down to the error. Definitely don't want `NaN`, which I saw showing up with the g++ code, since I was calling `acos` with an argument outside of -1 and 1.

Comment: The REALLY interesting question is why this goes wrong only in 64-bit builds (and with clang++ too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this piece of code:

```
// Computes the average point of the set of points
ii centroid(vii &pts)
{
    ii center(0LL, 0LL);
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        center.first += pts[i].first;
        center.second += pts[i].second;
    }

    center.first /= pts.size();     //right here!!
    center.second /= pts.size();

    return center;
}
```

I don't know why but g++ was taking the negative `center.first` and turning it into a positive, overflowed `long long` when dividing by the unsigned integer `pts.size`. By converting the statements into:

```
center.first /= (long long)pts.size();
center.second /= (long long)pts.size();
```

The output from g++ and VS c++ matches.

Comment: I think I get it. Because one side is unsigned, the other is also converted to unsigned. In the 32-bit case, it works fine, because `size_t` is `uint32_t`, but in 64-bit, `size_t` is the same as `uint64_t` (or `long long`), so the `pts.size()` converts the left-size of divide to `unsigned long long` (aka `uint64_t`) before dividing.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The interesting question is, why doesn't MSVC do the same - a bug in MSVC or the standard being lenient?